# Leer variable de entorno de cliente C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo una aplicación web hecha con C#, que se instala en un servidor a la cual acceden distintas terminales. Para identificar cada terminal tengo una variable de entorno de sistema creada en cada terminal a la cual tengo que acceder desde el servidor. Probé con Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable pero siempre me devuelve las variables del servidor.

Comment: De verdad, ¿Si el cliente accede desde android, linux, windows, IOS, MacOS, tienes una variable de entorno en cada cliente? ¿por qué necesitas identificarlo de esta manera?

Comment: Los clientes estan en una misma red?

Comment: Todo lo que se ejecute en el servidor, tomara las variables de entorno del servidor. Es mas, dudo que un cliente web te deje tomar variables de entorno de la pc donde se esta ejecutando. En tal caso, cada pagina deberia de alguna forma saber en que SO esta, y eso devolverselo al servidor

Comment: jachguate, si, tenemos una variable de entorno en cada cliente. Es un sistema de facturación que estamos migrando a web, el cual al momento para obtener info del cliente la obtenía de las variables de entorno.

Comment: Fran, están en la misma red si. Saludos.

Comment: Para empezar sí entiendes que todo el código lo ejecuta el servidor? por eso es servidor. No lograras obtener eso desde un cliente de esa manera, intenta con algo de Javascript

Comment: @Gonzalo, recuerda utilizar la notación [arroba]usuario para que el usuario reciba una notificación de tu _respuesta_ en comentarios. Casualmente pasé por aquí y me dí cuenta que _me respondiste_, pero eso es una _gran_ casualidad.

Comment: La pregunta del millón es, ¿por qué necesitas identificar a cada cliente mediante una variable de entorno?. Eso no estaba bien ni para sistemas de escritorio. Si estás migrando tu sistema de Desktop a Web, creo que no es mala idea que superes también esos detalles. Desconozco para que "lo identificas", pero lo que sea, se podrá hacer de otra forma que no requiera de una variable de entorno.

Comment: Tienes que reescribir esa porción de código y pensar en otra manera de lograr lo que hacías antes. Si ahora estás en un entorno web, lo que hacía el sistema anteriormente ya no tiene sentido

Answer (score 0):

Estas en un desarrollo web el codigo que ejecuta del lado del servidor solo tiene acceso a la PC donde esta hosteado

En cliente esta el browser que intepreta html y javascript, si necesitas la variable de entorno del cliente deberias enviarla en el request que haces al servidor.

[Reading environment variables with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315708/reading-environment-variables-with-javascript)

[Javascript environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770446/javascript-environment-variables)

Siempre esta la alternativa de probar usando

```
var ax = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
```

asignar el valor en algun hidden y enviarlo en el post

Pero la verdad no recomendaria que uses `ActiveXObject` este ya no es soportado por muchos browsers

Recuerda que acceder a informacion de la pc del usuario tiene problemas de seguridad, por eso esto que quieres hacer no estaria permitido

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, entiendo el tema de la seguridad y que iba a tener un problema cuando quisiera hacerlo. Estamos migrando un sistema de win a web y nos están apareciendo este tipo de problemas que vamos solucionando uno a uno. Gracias nuevamente